# DB2 Cutted trigger message

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have implemented a trigger with very large exception message, doing on this way

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '010101' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = MY_TEXT;
```

In case, this error occurs, the message is cut off. I think in DB2 LUW the max length is 1000 bytes.
Will be a possibility to show the whole message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on Db2-LUW the [documented](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-signal#sdx-synid_diagnostic-string-expression) limit on the length of the message_text is 70 bytes (not 1000 as per your question).  Any longer length gets truncated.

If you want to preserve the longer message then change your exception handler , for example to write the longer message into some table, or write it to a file or pipe etc.